# HTMLAgility Pack HtmlWeb "Cannot access a disposed object" Issue

Tags: .net, exception

VB.Net Project using visual Studio
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
HTMLAgility Pack

When I try to load a web page via the HtmlWeb Load method, I receive this error:

> Cannot access a disposed object

I put following code in the form load event. It doesn't get any simpler than this:

```
 Dim Web As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()

 Dim Document = Web.Load("https://scrapeme.live/shop/")
```

When the `Web.Load` event executes, I get the error.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.